# Dimension and Basis of the $S_2$ set of symmetric matrices with $tr(A)=0, \forall A \in S_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For the following problem:

> Let $S_2$ be the set of symmetric matrices (with real entries) and zero trace.
>
> 1. Prove that $S_2$ is a subspace of the space of all $M_{2\times2}$ matrices.
> 2. Find the dimension of $S_2$.
> 3. Find a basis for $S_2$.

So far I have proved that $S_2$ is indeed a subspace of $M_{2\times2}$ and since every element $A \in S_2$ has the form:
\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{a  &b \\ b &-a}
\end{equation}
I can deduce that a basis for $S_2$ could be
\begin{equation}
\beta=\left\{ \pmatrix{1  &0 \\0 &-1},\pmatrix{0  &1 \\1 &0}  \right\}
\end{equation}
What I am not sure how to prove is the fact that $\beta$ is indeed a basis *(linear independence)* and the dimension of it, if it is indeed a basis for $S_2$.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be confused by writing the basis.  Look at your original form.  Can you have the matrix equal zero with one of $a$ or $b$ not zero? How many degrees of freedom (free parameters) do you have?

Comment: @OskarLimka No that is not possible. It must be $a=b=0$ such that I get the zero matrix.

Comment: Now go and read the definition of linear independence and convince yourself that is exactly what it means: the only way to get $0$ is to put all coefficients to $0$.

Comment: @OskarLimka So the only think I have to do is just prove that in order to be $A=0$ it must be $a=b=0$. Got it. But what about the dimension?

Comment: The dimension is the number of elements in a basis....

Comment: Or the number of free coefficients (parameters) in your expression.

Comment: @GregMartin Ok guys, thanks! Sorry for trivial questions, I was just wondering if the dimension could be less that $2$, due to linear dependece. Anyway, that solved my problem, thanks!